# Printf with conditional format

Tags: c, format, printf, conditional-operator, comma-operator

I want to print number of variables based on `mode` value. Here is example:

```
char format[64] = {}
int mode_1, mode_2, mode_3;
int a,b,c,d,e,f;

...
// Get mode value here ....
...

// Build the format first
sprintf(format, "%s-%s-%s\n", mode_1 == 0 ? "a=%d,b=%d" : "a=%d",
                              mode_2 == 0 ? "c=%d,d=%d" : "c=%d",
                              mode_3 == 0 ? "e=%d,f=%d" : "e=%d");

// Print value here
printf(format, mode_1 == 0 ? (a,b) : a,
               mode_2 == 0 ? (c,d) : c,
               mode_3 == 0 ? (e,f) : f);
```

When I tried a simple example, the value printed when mode value is zero seems not right. What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: `When I tried a simple example` Please do not post screenshots. Please post text as text.

Comment: `?:` is an operator and as such it has 1 result value. You cannot use it to evaluate to multiple values or even to different number of results in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression

```
(a, b)
```

is an expression with the comma operator. The result of the expression is the value of the last operand.

That is this call

```
printf(format, mode == 0 ? (a,b): a);
```

in fact is equivalent to the call

```
printf(format, mode == 0 ? b: a);
```

Instead you could write

```
mode == 0 ? printf(format, a, b ) : printf( format, a );
```

If the form of the call of printf  depends on the integer variable `mode` then you could use for example a switch statement or if-else statements.

Comment: But actually I have more than 1 `mode` variable (in my sample code not in screenshot). So what should I do to make it simple?

Comment: @Tino You could use if-else statements or a switch statement.